# A strange uP timer problem

Tags: frequency, timer, microprocessor

We use STM32F2 at work, I recently face with a strange problem. I do not expect a direct answer from the crowd but I hope some pointers where to look at for root cause.

I have a clock that is 1MHz in frequency, the clock works well except a shadow frequency behind. 40KHz (something between 40 to 42KHz to be exact, I couldn't pin point). It seems a clock is drifting in some direction, these timers are implemented as counters and I cannot think of a scenario why I would see something in the background.

(I noticed problem in ADC reading first, so I know it is not a scope issue)

**UPDATE**
I am not in the office now, I will check with an analog scope today but basically, I sample a constant input with this clock (ADC is triggered as the rising edge of this clock). When I was analyzing data, I noticed a noise that is 40KHz and this is when I started looking which lead to this following picture.

Also, I use the Rigol's digital filter to make a LP filter up to 100KHz and I clearly see a signal at that frequency, small in amplitude but it is there. I will add a capture of that signal here too.

The scope capture attached. 
[image]

**UPDATE2**
More screenshots:

The one on the left at a different time scale. The one on the right both time scales with zoom function.
The bottom left is with 750Khz LP filter on. The bottom right one is swimsuit shot.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE and CONCLUSION**
It turns out this is really a scope issue, it is more than the aliasing, since the scope clearly shows some 40MHz background noise. We look at the potential issue with a high end scope and it is not there. (The root cause ADC issue is still there though, we just need to debug it)

Comment: What problem did you notice in ADC reading?

Comment: This looks like aliasing to me too.  Note that I'm not talking about aliasing due to the scope sampling, but aliasing on the display.  One cycle of your signal is not a integer number of pixels on the display.  It looks like it repeats in a pattern of about 24 cycles, so each cycle takes a whole number of pixels plus or minus 1/24 of a pixel to show.  Expand the time scale one level and this artifact should go away or look quite different.

Comment: Please clarify your question; I don't see a question here.

Comment: @supercat I added to the question, 40KHz noise that lead to this problem.

Comment: @user3685 try to reduce the time/division and say what happens!!!

Comment: @user3685 - I think people were talking about *reducing* the timebase (at least I was) So trying 2us/div, 1us/div, etc. Admittedly it could be confusing with "expand" "wind up" and "decrease" mentioned. You need to up the sample rate to eliminate aliasing (if present) Try it at 2us and 1us and post a shot of each if you can.

Comment: @user3685 - and try it with the 20MHz bandwidth limit on too (not the digital filter)

Comment: @OliGlaser it is still there. Here is another approach I have used to test. I trigger and than start moving the waveform to right side all the way to the edge. At the trigger point there is no drift since the scope is triggering at that point. When I go all the way to the righ, I see the rising edge is flickering to left and right, which proves to me that there is a problem. And it is weird, it is not like the whole chain is moving left and right, it is like a spring, compress and decompress. I hope this is a software bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like aliasing on the scope display to me.  How many samples are there on the screen?  What's the sample rate?

Wind up the timebase to show just a couple of clock cycles and see if looks better...

Comment: Run off the mill, low cost Rigol, 50MHz, 1GS/sec.

Comment: it turns out it is a RIgol issue. Today we look at this with a high end TEK scope, it is really a Scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the clock come from - the timer then output from the uC pin?

The first thing I would look for is something on your board that might generate noise at that frequency.
Have you got a switcher on the board?

Does the "shadow frequency" disappear if you drive it from a different power source?

Are you running from internal oscillator or crystal?

EDIT - aliasing is being mentioned, this sounds quite likely also. I had assumed you would have tried a few different timescales and got the same result. If you haven't done this, try decreasing the timescale a bit and see what it looks like. If you haven't got the bandwidth limit on apply this.
If you have an analogue scope handy check the signal on this - if the "shadow frequency" isn't present you know it's aliasing of some sort.

EDIT 2 - how have you implemented the pin toggle with the timer? Is it in an interrupt routine or done in main code? (i.e. just reading the timer or watching for the interrupt flag)
If it's the main code then it's possible another regular interrupt could fire during the counter update/pin toggle routine and throw the timing off.
Easiest way to test for this (if a possibility) would be to turn all other interrupts off and/or toggle the pin in the timer 2 interrupt routine.

Comment: Watchdog ............?

Comment: LOOKS potentially like aliasing. What scope?

Comment: @Russell - Good point. It's a Rigol so I'd expect it to be capable of at least 50MHz/1Gsps (probably running around 100Msps? in the capture displayed). Might be worth trying it with the bandwidth limit on (if it's not on already)

Comment: Clock comes from a timer pin. PA9 to be exact (Timer2, Channel2). I removed the 32KHz crystal on the board, that was my first instict. The capture after removing the 32KHz, I don't have anything else. I will try on a different board (ST"s Eval kit) today as well. No switcher, this is an ultra low noise system where there are no switchers, just LDOs. I will also try to run from the battery as well to see. CPU runs from a 25MHz crystal.

Comment: @OliGlaser what would the bw limit do for me?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon there is no watchdog in the system.

Comment: @user3685 - if it is a higher frequency aliasing, then cutting the bandwidth may remove/attenuate it. Say the sample rate is at 10Msps, and you have a 10.04MHz signal present, then it would alias as 40kHz - cutting the bandwidth to say 2MHz would attenuate the alias frequency and leave the 1MHz present. Note the filtering has to be done *before* the signal is sampled by the ADC (e.g. not digitally afterwards)

Comment: @OliGlaser Oli, if I must, later I can deal with it in the software but I really prefer not to have this artifact in my system and hence the quest for source of the problem.

Comment: @OliGlaser this is hardware programmed time, straight out of timer pin, there is no software involvement.